# Pass result of one query to another query and then merge results of these two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query:

```
SELECT name as String
     , COUNT(*) Total
     , SUM(product = 1) Product
           FROM String
                WHERE language = 1
           GROUP 
                BY name
           ORDER
                BY total desc
           LIMIT 10
```

Purpose of this query is to report TOP-10 of strings according to their occurrence in the `String` table, plus to report their occurrence in specific product (with id = 1).

I would like to add another column to the result which will count how many times each string occurs in the middle of another strings. For this purpose I have a table `Copy` that is indexed by Fulltext index.

My problem is to figure out how to pass the values of `String` column from result to this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) as inAll
    FROM Copy c
        WHERE MATCH(c.name) AGAINST (/*String*/)
```

Is it possible to achieve this result just by one SQL query?

```
Before:                   After:

String Total Product      String Total Product inAll
+-----+-----+------+      +-----+-----+-------+-----+
|blah | 52  |  12  |      |blah | 52  |  12   | 96  |
|bleh | 23  |  14  |      |bleh | 23  |  14   | 56  |
|bloh | 14  |  11  |      |bloh | 14  |  11   | 34  |
+-----+-----+------+      +-----+-----+-------+-----+
```

Thanks.

**Edit**

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Language (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; 

CREATE TABLE Product (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE String (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `label` VARCHAR(200),
    `name` TEXT(500) NOT NULL,
    `language` INT NOT NULL,
    `product` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE Copy (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` TEXT(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FULLTEXT(name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Plus `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` triggers.

Comment: MySQL does not allow using a subquery inside `AGAINST` so your current approach definitely will have to be reworked.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `String` and `Copy` tables?

Comment: Due to the old MySQL version, I cannot use Fulltext index on InnoDB table, so Copy table is just a copy of String table (id and name columns). I use String table for all queries which don't require to search in Fulltext index.

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining the `String` and `Copy` tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS inAll, t.String AS String, t.Total AS Total, t.Product AS Product
FROM Copy c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name AS String, COUNT(*) Total, SUM(product = 1) Product
    FROM String
    WHERE language = 1
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
    LIMIT 10
) t
ON c.name = t.name
```

Comment: I am getting error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: @akasummer I updated my query and it should run no without error.

Comment: Yes, it is working. Can I somehow get my additional columns back while using this query? Or I should change my approach as you wrote in the comment?

Comment: Your best bet is to a `JOIN` in this case.  Please post your schema.

Comment: Added schema to my post

Comment: @akasummer I updated my query again.  Try using a `JOIN`.

Comment: It works, but right now, `inAll` is just the same as `Total` but for all languages, i.e. not what I want.

Comment: I think it will be better to just do it in 2 separate queries. Execute first query, parse result in the backend, generate second query, execute it and then merge results?

Comment: Are the 2 counts the same?

Comment: Not the same. Since I just join on `c.name = t.name`, `inAll` count is equal to `select count(name) from Copy c where c.name = t.name`

Comment: Which count do you want?  The inner or outer one?  I can give you either.